# How would you write this using apply family of functions in R? Should you?

Tags: r, performance, csv, for-loop, apply

Here is my R Script that works just fine:

```
perc.rank <- function(x) trunc(rank(x)) / length(x) * 100.0

library(dplyr)
setwd("~/R/xyz")

datFm <- read.csv("yellow_point_02.csv")
datFm <- filter(datFm, HRA_ClassHRA_Final != -9999)
quant_cols <- c("CL_GammaRay_Despiked_Spline_MLR", "CT_Density_Despiked_Spline_FinalMerged",
                "HRA_PC_1HRA_Final", "HRA_PC_2HRA_Final","HRA_PC_3HRA_Final",
                "SRES_IMGCAL_SHIFT2VL_Slab_SHIFT2CL_DT", "Ultrasonic_DT_Despiked_Spline_MLR")
# add an extra column to datFm to store the quantile value
for (column_name in quant_cols) {
  datFm[paste(column_name, "quantile", sep = "_")] <- NA
}
# initialize an empty dataframe with the new column names appended
newDatFm <- datFm[0,]
# get the unique values for the hra classes
hraClassNumV <- sort(unique(datFm$HRA_ClassHRA_Final))
# loop through the vector and create currDatFm and append it to newDatFm
for (i in hraClassNumV) {
  currDatFm <- filter(datFm, HRA_ClassHRA_Final == i)
  for (column_name in quant_cols) {
    currDatFm <- within(currDatFm,
                        {
                          CL_GammaRay_Despiked_Spline_MLR_quantile <- perc.rank(currDatFm$CL_GammaRay_Despiked_Spline_MLR)
                          CT_Density_Despiked_Spline_FinalMerged_quantile <- perc.rank(currDatFm$CT_Density_Despiked_Spline_FinalMerged)
                          HRA_PC_1HRA_Final_quantile <- perc.rank(currDatFm$HRA_PC_1HRA_Final)
                          HRA_PC_2HRA_Final_quantile <- perc.rank(currDatFm$HRA_PC_2HRA_Final)
                          HRA_PC_3HRA_Final_quantile <- perc.rank(currDatFm$HRA_PC_3HRA_Final)
                          SRES_IMGCAL_SHIFT2VL_Slab_SHIFT2CL_DT_quantile <- perc.rank(currDatFm$SRES_IMGCAL_SHIFT2VL_Slab_SHIFT2CL_DT)
                          Ultrasonic_DT_Despiked_Spline_MLR_quantile <- perc.rank(currDatFm$Ultrasonic_DT_Despiked_Spline_MLR)
                        }
                       )
  }
  newDatFm <- rbind(newDatFm, currDatFm)
}
newDatFm <- newDatFm[order(newDatFm$Core_Depth),]
# head(newDatFm, 10)
write.csv(newDatFm, file = "Ricardo_quantiles.csv")
```

I have a few questions though.  Every R book or video that I have read or watched, recommends using the 'apply' family of language constructs over the classic 'for' loop stating that apply is much faster.

So the first question is:  how would you write it using apply (or tapply or some other apply)?

Second, is this really true though that apply is much faster than for?  The csv file 'yellow_point_02.csv' has approx. 2500 rows.  This script runs almost instantly on my Macbook Pro which has 16 Gig of memory.

Third, See the 'quant_cols' vector?  I created it so that I could write a generic loop (for columm_name in quant_cols) ....But I could not make it to work.  So I hard-coded the column names post-fixed with '_quantile' and called the 'perc.rank' many times.  Is there a way this could be made dynamic?  I tried the 'paste' stuff that I have in my script, but that did not work.

On the positive side though, R seems awesome in its ability to cut through the 'Data Wrangling' tasks with very few statements.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you [make this example reproducible and minimal](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: It seems that you're trying to apply `perc.rank` to the columns of a "data.frame" (only those columns contained in `quant_cols`) grouped by `HRA_ClassHRA_Final`? Take a look in `?aggregate`, `?tapply`, `?split` forms. As an example of what I understand you're trying to achieve: with data `dat = data.frame(group = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 4, 2), val1 = runif(10), val2 = runif(10), val3 = runif(10)); cols = paste("val", 1:3, sep = "")` see `do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dat[cols], dat$group), function(x) as.data.frame(lapply(x, perc.rank))))` which follows the concept of split-apply-combine.